# How to get the Class of selected object in Blender 2.8?

Tags: python

What is the python code to get the Class() of selected object in Blender 2.8 ? I want to know if the selected object is grease pencil or any other.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selected class is not retrievable for every object, as that code is defined in C, not in Python. But the body of your question asks for the `type` anyways, so here you go:

```
objectType = bpy.context.object.type
```

This will yield one of the following strings in Blender2.8 (which I assume you use, as in 2.79 there are no Grease Pencil Objects):

```
"MESH"
"CURVE"
"SURFACE"
"META"
"FONT"
"ARMATURE"
"LATTICE"
"EMPTY"
"GPENCIL"
"CAMERA"
"LIGHT"
"SPEAKER"
"LIGHT_PROBE"
```

To get an updated type list (as the API changes sometimes), you can use the following code with an active object:

```
import bpy

types = bpy.context.object.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items

for t in types:
    print('type %s: %s' %(t.identifier, t.name))
```

Result in py console (2.8)

```
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data

>>> C.object.__class__
<class 'bpy_types.Object'>

>>> types = C.object.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items
>>> 
>>> for t in types:
...     print('type %s: %s' %(t.identifier, t.name))
...     
type MESH: Mesh
type CURVE: Curve
type SURFACE: Surface
type META: Meta
type FONT: Font
type ARMATURE: Armature
type LATTICE: Lattice
type EMPTY: Empty
type GPENCIL: GPencil
type CAMERA: Camera
type LIGHT: Light
type SPEAKER: Speaker
type LIGHT_PROBE: Probe
```

Comment: Is there a difference between bpy_types.Object and bpy.types.Object? It seems like the actual type is defined in bpy.types, but what does bpy_types refer to?

Comment: @AnsonSavage `bpy_types` is the name of the Python file located in `//your_blender_installation/blender_version/scripts/modules`. It contains classes and functions which are apparently called when you ask for the type, returning the required info for you. Guess this is kind of a wrapper module.