# Object Active Selected With Python

Tags: python

I want to use this add-on, so the Python code has to be Single line
https://github.com/InamuraJIN/CommandRecorder

I was able to select Empty in this Python
`bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Empty")`
However, this command does not select the object in Python as active

I don't want it
Python allowed me to select objects with matching names
But it's not Active Select.

I want to do.
Active selection of the currently selected object + specified Name Object
[image]
I use Google Translate

Comment: Hi! Having a hard time to understand what you'd like to do. You can get the current selection by using `bpy.context.selected_objects` and filter the selection by type via `Object.type`: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132825/python-selecting-object-by-name-in-2-8/132829#132829 Alternatively: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125114/how-to-get-the-class-of-selected-object-in-blender-2-8  Does that help? Otherwise please take your time, edit your question and explain in detail what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Thank you.
I've just added the Image

Comment: No problem. Means you'd like to be able to select and highlight all objects starting with "Cube"? ...or only one object matching the "Cube" string? What's the reason using this add-on?

Comment: Active selection if the object name is an exact match to "Cube".
And we want to keep the currently selected object in the multiple selection state
I'm thinking about joining afterwards, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You would have to set the active object via `ViewLayer`. Did you already tried: `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Cube")` as suggested in the answer I've linked to? Also, if you'd like to join objects you can override the operator: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133024/31447 so no need to set the active object...

Comment: Thank you.
This code doesn't seem to be able to select Active
I want to run the state of the manual selection at the end of this video in Python. https://i.imgur.com/2V6GTqz.mp4

Comment: Head over to the scripting workspace and use the console to test (works).

Comment: This add-on, just like PhotoShop's Action, allows you to register and execute multiple simple tasks
I think this Active Select will help me in many ways

Comment: For some reason, it looks like only the pivot is selected

Comment: If so (the pivot is selected), you nailed it, done.

Comment: What's "Nailed"?”
Active object is not a selected mesh”
I get an error message like this

Comment: As we all know, cubes are meshes so it seems your cube is not the "active object" for whatever reason. Also, you most likely have to select it as well: `bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Cube").select_set(True)` depending on what you do...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/quLTCLO.mp4
Thank you so much!
I put those two lines together and it was properly selected!
It's no problem if you can't do it, but is it possible to make these on one line?
By the way, you can't use ";".

Comment: I guess, you can not combine both lines - I'm not sure what the add-on is doing under the hood though. Can't test it really, the addon crashes all the time when running it on blender 2.83/linux.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.
Oh. I'm Windows. can you see the error message?
I don't know if I can handle it, but I'd like to make it a to-do list